# Actionbar tab width and badge implementation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**Dears,**

Take a look on the screen shot:

[image: Alert]

**The problem:**

1. Unable to set the width of the tab.
2. The badge always overlapped with tab text.

**Code of badge:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_background_select" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/font_color"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        style="@style/txtBadge"
        android:text="99"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Style:**

```
<style name="txtBadge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignTop">@id/tabTitle</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignRight">@id/tabTitle</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item> 
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/badge_design</item>           
</style
```

Any help? 
Tried to change the width but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/06/24/adding-a-badge-to-an-actionbar-tab check out this solution if you still not get the answer ...